# Ajax post calls controller function, but it recieves a null value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

how are you all doing?. I've beeing struggeling the whole day with a issue on my project. The project its developed on NET Framework (not CORE).

When i'm trying to add a new item to my DB the function in my controller gets called but it recieves empty data.

Things i tryed:

1. Change the way my $.ajax es writen
2. Change the way my JSON data is writen
3. Change the way my Controller function retrieves the data (with a string, a auto-generated Object from the MVC, and with a my-own build object)

I sincerely have no clue why this is happening, any tip would be highly appreciated.

My controller function :

```
public class ModelToImport
    {
        public int IdModelo { get; set; }
     
        public string CodigoInterno { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public string AreaFuncional { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public string Nombre { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public string Descripcion { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaModificacion { get; set; } = new DateTime();
        public string Estado { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UltimaEjecucion { get; set; }= new DateTime();
        public string Tipo { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Responsable { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public bool Importado { get; set; } = false;

        public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; } = new DateTime();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public  void CreateNewModel( string model)
    {
      /*  Modelo modelo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Modelo>(json);

        if (modelo != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Modelo.Add(modelo);
                db.SaveChangesAsync();
                RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }*/
    }
```

My client-side ajax and data:

```
var codigoInterno = document.getElementById("CodigoInterno").value;
        var areaFuncional = document.getElementById("AreaFuncional").value;
        var nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value;
        var descripcion = document.getElementById("modelDescription").value;

        var tipo = document.getElementById("typeModel");
        tipo = tipo.options[tipo.selectedIndex].value;

        var usuario = document.getElementById("userModel");
        usuario = usuario.options[usuario.selectedIndex].value;


        var importado = document.getElementById("Importado").checked;

        var myNewModel = {
            "CodigoInterno": { codigoInterno },
            "AreaFuncional": { areaFuncional },
            "Nombre": { nombre },
            "Descripcion": { descripcion },
            "Estado": "En desarrollo",
            "Tipo": { tipo },
            "Responsable": { usuario },
            "Importado": { importado },
            "FechaCreacion":  getCurrentDateTime() 
        }

        console.log(myNewModel);
        myNewModel = JSON.stringify(myNewModel).toString();
        console.log(myNewModel);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateNewModel", "Modelos")',
            data: JSON.stringify(myNewModel),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType : "json"
        }).done(function () {
            window.alert("success");
        });
```

[Browser Ouput: ][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ujsM.png

[Server Side Output:][2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAi33.png

Thank you in advance for any help and my most sincere greetings.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried?:

```
public  void CreateNewModel( ModelToImport model)
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Hi Brad! thanks for your reply, yes, i did :)